# How to add Propertysheethandler extension registered with my shell extension?

Tags: windows, shell-extensions

I have created windows shell extension like google drive, for specific filetype in my windows.
I have registered propertysheethandler extension.

When I open that type of file in my drive shell extension in property of files I am unable to get propertysheethandler page.

Comment: Do you see the whole Properties dialog? Is it just your PSH that doesn't appear? Does your PSH works outside of your drive for this file type? They are supposed to work anywhere.

Comment: yes , i can see properties dialog. PSH works well outside of my drive in normal windows folder when i open properties of file.

Comment: Is the file in your extension a real physical file? Do you open the properties dialog by yourself or you let the system do it? It will be difficult to help w/o some code or reproducing project.

Comment: yes , files in my extension are real files they are refering to windows folder. also i have enabled "SFGAO_HASPROPSHEET" to display properties , but some custom properties which is registered with propertisheethandler for some .{extension} file. that is not visible in my extension but visible in windows explorer properties